# retrieve column id of csv file

Tags: c, linux, file, csv

I want to ask if there is any way through which I can retrieve column numbers of a csv file using C programming? Those numbers which are by default set in csv file and also the row names i-e :

A B C.............. Z AA AB AC...........

Comment: Welcome to C, where there's nothing stopping you as long as you're happy to do it yourself.

Comment: i will definitely do it but need a little guidance

Comment: CSV files don't have column or row ids.  Do you just mean the column or row index (0, 1, 2, etc.)?  Can't you just maintain a counter?

Comment: yes how to retrieve the column index. actually i need those indexes to insert value in that particular row and column                                                                 thanks

Comment: This seems like someone's trying to get their homework down for them to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry randy, but you've got some big misconceptions about this.  CSV files are pretty much text files like you'd create in notepad that happen to have commas between the words/values.  If you want to read them in C, you can parse each line using scanf() - either:

- write a program that can only work with one particular layout of fields: as in...

  ```
  char name[128]; int age; int height_cm; int weight_kg;

  while (scanf("%.128[^,],%d,%d,%d", name, &age, &height_cm, &weight_kg) == 4)
  // do something with the values just read...
  ```
- try parsing the fields as various types until you get a failure:

  ```
  char buffer[128];
  char delimiter;
  int num_fields;

  while ((num_fields = scanf("%.128[^,]%c", buffer, delimiter)) >= 1)
  {
  // use e.g. strtod to see if the field might be reasonably interpreted as a double
  ...

  if (num_fields == 1 || delimiter != 'c')
      break; // end of line...
  }
  ```

Edit in response to comment/question below:

Sorry - I just don't understand what you're asking.  What is "increasing" data?  If you mean the file has different lines representing distinct rows, and has more than one column, then yes that's normal and it can be parsed by the approach I listed above.  If you mean to ask "how can you save the rows/columns for some future processing", then you can create a structure with the fields (if you know want to hardcode the column names and types), or use an array (perhaps of char data initially).  You can then have an array (or linked list if you have a library for that) of those structures/arrays.  For example:

```
static const int Max_Persons = 1000;

struct Person { char name[128]; int age; int height_cm; int weight_kg; };

Person persons[Max_Persons];
int num_persons = 0;  // how many read from CSV file so far?

while (scanf("%.128[^,],%d,%d,%d",
             persons[num_persons].name, &persons[num_persons].age,
             &persons[num_persons].height_cm,
             &persons[num_persons].weight_kg) == 4)
    if (++num_persons == Max_Persons)
    {
        printf("WARNING: can only handle the first %d people, ignoring rest\n",
               Max_Persons);
        break;
    }
```

This would read (from standard input - switch to using fopen() and fscanf() if you want to read directly from a named file) up to MAX_LINES "Person" rows.

If you don't know the number and types of data you need to use the alternative (more complicated) approach I listed earlier: trying to pass each field until there's a failure, checking for end-of-comma-separated fields versus end-of-file.  Off-the-top-of-my-head and untested, something like:

```
struct Field { char buf[Max_Field_Len]; };
struct Row { Field r[Max_Columns]; };
Data Row[Max_Rows];
int num_columns = 0;
int current_column = 0;
int num_rows = 0;
int num_fields;
char delimiter;
while ((num_fields = scanf("%[^,]%c", Row[num_rows][current_column].buf, &delimiter)) >= 1)
{
    if (++current_column > num_columns)
        num_columns = current_column;
    if (num_fields == 2 && delimiter != ',')
    {
        current_column = 0;
        ++num_rows;
    }
    else if (num_fields == 1)
        break; // end-of-file
}
```

Comment: Tony sir thanks a lot. actually in my program the data will be increasing in both direction ie in rows and column is their a way to handle it. thanks

Comment: @randy: I've tried to add more detail in an edit to the answer.

Comment: thanks Tony sir thanks so much for your help and concern .actually i m filling data in csv file at run time data will be updated countinously dnt have predefined fields ie column name and row name.at run time i have to add new colum or row but the problem is that for eg i have row 1 having 3 col filled then i move to row 2 fill lets say 2 column but how to move the to pointer to again row 1 to fill column 4 thanks

Comment: randy: the actual CSV file on disk won't have existing space to insert new columns: you have to read the rest of the file, then use the seek function on the FILE stream to return to the point where you want to insert a new column, write that column value then write out the rest of the file again.  If you concentrate too narrowly on that problem then you'll write an inflexible system.  Instead, think three stages: read the CSV file, perform multiple manipulations in memory, then overwrite the CSV file with the modified data.  Code above is a very basic way to get the current CSV data into mem.